# CSS3 Firefox not recognizing my liner gradient color

Tags: css, firefox

Im trying to use this code in css to display a linear gradient background but Im not sure why firefox is not displaying it..

```
body
{
height: 100%;
/*background-color: #F0F0F0;*/
background-repeat: repeat-x;

/* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#C0C0C0), to(#F0F0F0));

/* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C0C0C0, #F0F0F0);

/* Firefox 3.6+ */
background: -moz-gradient(top, #C0C0C0, #F0F0F0);

/* IE 10 */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #C0C0C0, #F0F0F0);

/* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C0C0C0, #F0F0F0);
}
```

Im not sure what is my problem.. I have tried different ways changing top, bottom, putting % but still is not working..
I will really appreciate any help..

Comment: No unprefixed gradient is always a red flag.

Comment: @BoltClock I seriously can't wait until the day that is not the case...

Comment: I thought it was `linear-gradient`, not `-moz-gradient`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No need for the `background-repeat` property on gradients as gradients fill the entire y- and x-axis of whatever element it is applied to (unless your background is a pattern, in which case you may want to change other parts of your code,) and
2. `-moz-gradient` is incorrect, it should be `-moz-linear-gradient`

Comment: If the background was a pattern you might actually want to repeat it. What you will most likely want to add is background-attachment: fixed; though. (you'll see)

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy.. I missed that one.. Thats why looking to other peoples code is good.. missing wording and stuffs like that is sometimes easier for others..

Comment: @JV17 Yeah that's happened to me a few times before too. ;)

Comment: Actually, it should also just be "linear-gradient", with no vendor prefix at all, because otherwise this code will break in standards-compliant browsers that don't implement any vendor prefixing for gradients.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing linear in -moz

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C0C0C0, #F0F0F0);
```